# How to perform a query for three values where two values includes a range in Cloud Firestore (cloud_firestore: ^0.13.4+2)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am programming an app in which one user can filter other users according to the following criteria: age in a range, weight in a range and rank.

The problem I have is that only one of the listed values is filtered. A .where .where .where link probably does not work and at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries it says that the command whereEqualTo should be used. However, this command is not recognized by my IDE.

Does anyone know how I can write such a query? I have not listed a code example because I would appreciate a general method. I can't find anything about it on the internet.

Thanks in advance for your help!

This is my code:

```
query() {
if (currentUser.rank == 'Gold') {
  return docRef
      .where('Rank', isEqualTo: 'Gold')
      .where('age',
          isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: int.parse(currentUser.ageRange['min']))
      .where('age',
          isLessThanOrEqualTo: int.parse(currentUser.ageRange['max']))
      .orderBy('age', descending: false);
} else if (currentUser.rank == 'Silver') {
  return docRef
      .where('Rank', isEqualTo: 'Silver')
      .where('age',
          isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: int.parse(currentUser.ageRange['min']))
      .where('age',
          isLessThanOrEqualTo: int.parse(currentUser.ageRange['max']))
      .orderBy('age', descending: false);
} else if (currentUser.rank == 'Bronze') {
  return docRef
      .where('Rank', isEqualTo: 'Bronze')
      .where('age',
          isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: int.parse(currentUser.ageRange['min']))
      .where('age',
          isLessThanOrEqualTo: int.parse(currentUser.ageRange['max']))
      .orderBy('age', descending: false);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a code example it's a bit hard to give a proper solution.  But reading the link you include above, you cannot have range filters on different fields.  Which it sounds like you are trying to do.  This is due to a limitation of the Firestore database.  You'll have to figure out another way to filter using only equality operators.  Or a combo of 1 equality filter and 1 range filter (as I did below).

Easier thing to do would be to do the filtering client-side after you get the results from the database, filter the results in Flutter (client-side).  Beware though, this might cause more data transfer to and from Firestore which may cost you more cloud expense.

You can do as much filtering in the Firestore query as allowed:

```
var result = firestoreInstance
  .collection("users")
  .where("rank", isEqualTo: "1")
  .where("age", isGreaterThan: 40)
  .get();
```

Flutter / Client Side:

```
var resultsFilteredByWeight = result.docs.where((result) => result.weight >= 100 && result.weight <= 150);
```

Not sure I have the exact syntax correct here without a workable example but this should give you an idea of what to do.

Comment: Thank you @jaredbaszler, this helped me a little bit, to understand the query options in firestore! I add to my question my code that I have used. Would you please look over it and tell me, what exactly I can do. :)

Comment: Of course just to query for example for Rank and age at the same time. I understood what you sayed, that firestore don't support querying in different values by range.

Comment: But I think that my where where method is not the right way how to do it, because when I compile this, it shows me no error but do not show any content in the app... :(

Comment: Based on your code above, you are still querying by `range` on two different fields.  You can't use `isGreaterThanOrEqualTo` on both `age` and `weight` fields.  You have to only use that on 1 field and then filter the other on the client side like I explained above.  You won't get any compile time errors with this as these are simply limitations of the Firestore.

Comment: Yes, I have understood what you have told me. But my problem is, even when I just query for the Rank and the age range, what probably should work, lead to it that no information would be displayed. I changed my code and let only  the Rank and the age range over but it gave me the same result. I do not understand this. I edit my above code to show you how I tested it. This problem is confusing me...

Comment: Per the examples in the link above, you may not be able to do two different range operations on the same property.  So take out the `"max"` `isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:` filter out of all your examples and see if that works.  If so, then you will have to go with that server side and do the rest of your filtering client side.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. For all those who have problems with the queries in Firestore, the IDE, for example Android Studio or Xcode, show the error in RUN that is caused by your query. In my case, the multi-index method was not activated in Cloud Firestore, so of course nothing was displayed to me. To do this, you simply have to click on the link that is displayed in RUN, and you will be redirected directly to Firestore and Firestore will make the necessary changes for you, very user-friendly! I also tested it again with my original code and it said the same thing as jaredbaszler had already said. A range query in two separate values ​​is not possible. It is, however, possible to do a range query in a value and to link this to another value query (a simple connection with .where .where .where). I haven't tested how many other values ​​can be linked, but another one works without problems. I think there is a possibility to add more. I hope I was able to help others who have problems with it. And once again, big thanks to @jaredbaszler for giving me the right mindset to solve the problem! :)